# Filtering polygons based on text input in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to work out a variation on the mapbox code provided in this tutorial here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers-by-input/

But instead of filtering individual points, I'm trying to figure out how to filter polygons from a GeoJSON that have names appended based on an integer feature. Basically, I want to be able to enter the appended name of a polygon into a text box and have the map filter to just that polygon. I'm having difficulty identifying which parts of the code in the example to isolate and graft over. Has anyone tried something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "filter to just that polygon", I think what you mean (in geospatial terms) is "filter to show only points within that polygon".

You will want to use Turf's "[`booleanWithin`](https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanWithin)" function.

You will want to change this code:

```
layerIDs.forEach(function(layerID) {
    map.setLayoutProperty(layerID, 'visibility',
      layerID.indexOf(value) > -1 ? 'visible' : 'none');
    });
```

You will have to iterate over the points themselves (not just their IDs), and use the booleanWithin function to check whether the point is within the polygon that you have somewhere else loaded.